# Passing function as argument, with capture, what type to declare in function?

Tags: c++

This probably has a simple resolution, but can't find the right combination.

I'm trying to setup a function (`setupScreen`) to take as an argument a function to do the actual setup:

```cpp
void ScreenHelpers::setupScreen(void (*setupFunc)(ThinkInk_290_Tricolor_Z10*)){
    ScreenHelpers::waitTilCanRefreshScreen();

    (* setupFunc)(&display_two);

    lastUpdateTime = millis();
}
//...
void ScreenHelpers::displayErrorMessage(const String message){
    const char* text = message.c_str();
    ScreenHelpers::setupScreen([text](ThinkInk_290_Tricolor_Z10* screen) {
        screen->clearBuffer();
        ScreenHelpers::simpleDisplayText(
            screen,
            text,
            EPD_RED
        );
     });
}
```

This works, until I added the `[text]` to capture the `text` variable in the lambda, where it resulted in:

```
ScreenHelpers.cpp: In static member function 'static void ScreenHelpers::displayErrorMessage(String)':
ScreenHelpers.cpp:45:4: error: no matching function for call to 'ScreenHelpers::setupScreen(ScreenHelpers::displayErrorMessage(String)::<lambda(ThinkInk_290_Tricolor_Z10*)>)'
   });
    ^
ScreenHelpers.cpp:21:6: note: candidate: 'static void ScreenHelpers::setupScreen(void (*)(ThinkInk_290_Tricolor_Z10*))'
 void ScreenHelpers::setupScreen(void (*setupFunc)(ThinkInk_290_Tricolor_Z10*)){
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What should my function declaration look like to accept this?

Comment: This is not an Arduino specific question, it is a pure C++ issue. Please ask this at [so], if you still don't know how to do it, after doing the necessary research.

Comment: I have to disagree, Arduino's C++ is an odd subset of the language. I'd argue it is reasonable to look to Arduino-specific places for advanced language features.

Comment: The compiler used by the Arduino is a standard GNU C++ compiler targeting the AVR or ARM processor. As such it is not really limited in the **language**, and we program in standard C++. But the accompanied **C++ libraries** can be incomplete, for example `<functional>` might be missing, granted. -- So it had helped if you had mentioned your specific Arduino target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ScreenHelpers::setupScreen()` expects its argument to be a plain
function. A capturing lambda is not a plain function: it is rather a
functor, i.e. an object that is callable like a function.

The standard way of passing such a lambda in C++ is to declare the
parameter to be of type [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

```cpp
#include <functional>

void ScreenHelpers::setupScreen(std::function<void(ThinkInk_290_Tricolor_Z10*)> setupFunc) {
    ...
}
```

This may or may not work depending on the Arduino board you are using.
AVR-based boards rely on a C library that only minimally supports C++.
You cannot use `<functional>` on those boards. If you are using one of
those boards, your options are:

1. Try to find an implementation of of the C++ STL for AVR-based boards.
   I have seen at least one floating around in the Net.
2. Use the standard C idiom for defining a callback with a `void*`
   parameter:

```cpp
void ScreenHelpers::setupScreen(
      void (*setupFunc)(ThinkInk_290_Tricolor_Z10*, void*),
      void *callback_data) {
   setupFunc(&display_two, callback_data);
   //...
}

// elsewhere:
ScreenHelpers::setupScreen([](ThinkInk_290_Tricolor_Z10 *screen, void *data) {
   const char *text = (const char *) data;
   // ...
}, (void *) text);
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like my board supports the lambdas, making things easy!

The second option crossed my mind too, was also thinking maybe making the `*data` param a varargs.